# Which IOC Container runs in medium trust

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, medium-trust

Hi I am trying to get a website running with Mosso that has Castle Windsor as my IOC, however I am getting the following error.

```
[SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
   GoldMine.WindsorControllerFactory..ctor() in WindsorControllerFactory.cs:33
   GoldMine.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs:70
```

My questions are

1. Does Castle Windsor run under medium trust?
2. Can I download the DLL's without having to recompile with nant? (as I don't have this set up and don't know nant at all)
3. Or is there another IOC that I can use that I can download and works in Medium Trust?

Thanks

Comment: **EDIT** After looking at my options I decided to go down the unity route. Once I got my head around the docs and found some examples I have it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Windsor stance seems to be doc'd / discussed here](http://castle.uservoice.com/forums/16605-official-castle-project-feedback-forum/suggestions/433388-provide-binaries-with-allowpartiallytrustedcallers)

[LinFu seems to](http://plaureano.blogspot.com/2009/02/common-service-locator-adapter-for.html)

[StructureMap seems to as of 2.5](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/02/01/structuremap-2-5-3-is-released-and-the-future-of-structuremap.aspx). [SM 2.6 has no Reflection.Emit](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2010/02/04/structuremap-2-6-and-2-5-4-is-released.aspx)

A good Bingoogleable keyword is `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute`

Comment: Ninject 2 is my favorite. Unity and AutoFac also both work in medium trust.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) runs in Medium Trust!

Comment: Is this a shamless plug! :) +1 Thanks for this, I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

The repository has moved, you can find all new links here now http://www.castleproject.org/git.html