# asp.net within a hosted environment and Castle.Windsor -> Required permissions cannot be acquired

Tags: asp.net, iis, castle-windsor, hosted

I am developing an asp.net 3.5 web application which is running perfectly on my local IIS server but gets me into a lot of trouble when publishing it to a hosted (1and1) environment.

When the web.config is loaded an "System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired." exception is thrown. The stack trace indicates that this is caused by my using of the Castle.Windsor framework:

> [PolicyException: Required permissions cannot be acquired.]
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) +7606231
>   System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence,
>   PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset,
>   PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean
>   checkExecutionPermission) +57
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or
>   one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)]
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +0    System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound,
>   Boolean forIntrospection) +43
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +127
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +142    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +203    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +105
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath
>   configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
>   +54    System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +232
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +51
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +337
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +58    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +512
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>   +729
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.Windsor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. Failed to
>   grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131417)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8921851
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +333

I am pretty limited in investigate this problem due to the hosted environment restrictions - specifically I am unable to review the the machine.config and the IIS configuration. The one fact I know for sure is that it is running on a 2.0.50727.5456 framework... The hosters customer service is neither competent nor willing to help so I have to do it on my own.

Any suggestions how to take a deeper look into the causes or how to simply resolve this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that 1&1 uses a general medium trust-level for all hosted asp.net applications. It strongly seems that Castle Windsor is not able to run under such an permission-restricted environment (for instance reflection is not available there).

Fortunately there are a lot of alternatives (see [which-ioc-runs-in-medium-trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200810/which-ioc-runs-in-medium-trust)) which can be used under such circumstances. I simply used [simple injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/) which is a tiny (but for my purposes powerful-enough) IoC container and it does a great job and solved all my permission-problems.